# ConcurrentModificationException not occour when adding dublicate element

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

iterator does not give the concurrent modification exception when we adding duplicate element while traversing the list.what is the reason?

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myMap.put("1", "1");
    myMap.put("2", "2");
    myMap.put("3", "3");
    Iterator<String> it1 = myMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext()){
        String key = (String) it1.next();
        System.out.println("Map Value:"+myMap.get(key));
        if(key.equals("2")){
            myMap.put("1","4");
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of `HashMap`: *"Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: **the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs**."*

Answer (score 1):

Since you are updating the existing key value in the myMap, its size has not been changed and you are not getting ConcurrentModificationException.

> If you are wondering how Iterator checks for the modification, its implementation is present in AbstractList class where an int variable modCount is defined. modCount provides the number of times list size has been changed. modCount value is used in every next() call to check for any modifications in a function checkForComodification().

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite an entry of the map, so the iterator works in spit of that since the `iterator()` check concerns the structural modification of the map.
Add a new entry and it will throw the exception `myMap.put("4","4");`.
Note that actually the behavior you noticed is an implementation detail and that even if it works you should not consider it as a valid code.
To be conform with the Map API specification you don't have to change the map with the object referenced that when you use an iterator.

[`Map.keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) specifies indeed :

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress
>   (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of
>   the iteration are undefined